# registerListener in Android, causes an Error when implementing SensorEventListener

Tags: android, sensors

I took an example of implementing `SensorEventListner` from [here](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c427a981-b4af-49cb-a7dc-4b1a764ef628),and he shows the AVD result which means that it is working the source code is just here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    Float azimut = 0.0f; 
    CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;
    Sensor magnetometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
        setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);    // Register the sensor listeners
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }



    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    private class CustomDrawableView extends View {

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            int centerx = width / 2;
            int centery = height / 2;
            canvas.drawLine(centerx, 0, centerx, height, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(0, centery, width, centery, paint);

            // Rotate the canvas with the azimut      
            if (azimut != null) {
                canvas.rotate(-azimut * 360 / (2 * 3.14159f), centerx, centery);
            }
            paint.setColor(0xffffffff);
            canvas.drawLine(centerx, -1000, centerx, +1000, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(-1000, centery, 1000, centery, paint);
            canvas.drawText("N", centerx + 1, centery - 10, paint);
            canvas.drawText("S", centerx - 1, centery + 15, paint);
            paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener)this, (Sensor)accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        mSensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener)this,(Sensor) magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    float[] mGravity;
    float[] mGeomagnetic;

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            Log.v("ACCELEROMETER", "ACCELEROMETER");
            mGravity = event.values;
        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            Log.v("MAGNETIC_FIELD", "MAGNETIC_FIELD");
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;
        }

        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float first[] = new float[9];
            float second[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(first, second, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(first, orientation);
                azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
            }
        }
        mCustomDrawableView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

All things work if I comment the two code lines of `onResume` method (on AVK and on tablet). I don,t know if I have to write something in the XML files to authorize the using of sensors, or I have to activate something in my tablet, I am using version 4.2 of android

Comment: If you want any help at all, you need to post more info. What error do you get?

Comment: @Kaediil, hello. it doesn't work just with starting it closes writting "unfortunately MainActivity has stopped "

Comment: Log cat then.  There is some reason it is failing.  Did you run it in the debugger?  What is the exception?

Comment: @Kaediil, I am sorry, it was very night, I found the error, it was at  `public void onAccuracyChanged` method it doesn't exist at the source from where I got this example but with Netbeans I should override it. Automatically Netbeans generates `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` this caused me the problem (I don't know why) so I comment it and it is runnig well. Thank you Mr Kaediil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, the error  was at `public void onAccuracyChanged` method it doesn't exist at the source from where I got this example but with I should override it.

Automatically Netbeans generates `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` when you override abstract methods. So all in the example is well except the line `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` that you have to make like comment.